# findMeetingTimes API Permissions Issues

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I have been trying to access findMeetingTime API but everytime I try to do it, I get an error.My App has the permission (delegated) allowed.

I am confused about things below and what does it mean by application now supported

Permission type Permissions (from least to most privileged)
Delegated (work or school account)  **Calendars.Read.Shared, Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared**
Delegated (personal Microsoft account)  **Not supported**.
Application **Not supported**.

Can someone explain the process.

**Error**

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadArgument",
        "message": "Invalid user address",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "929f6e29-694b-4fbc-a789-bd679403ab63",
            "date": "2019-04-22T23:15:43"
        }
    }
}
```

**Request**

```
{
  "attendees": [
    {
      "type": "required",
      "emailAddress": {
        "name": "M",
        "address": "xx.xxxx@xxxxx.com"
      }
    }
  ],
  "locationConstraint": {
    "isRequired": "false",
    "suggestLocation": "false",
    "locations": [
      {
        "resolveAvailability": "false",
        "displayName": "xxx"
      }
    ]
  },
  "timeConstraint": {
    "activityDomain": "work",
    "timeslots": [
      {
        "start": {
          "dateTime": "2019-04-16T09:00:00",
          "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
        },
        "end": {
          "dateTime": "2019-04-18T17:00:00",
          "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "isOrganizerOptional": "false",
  "meetingDuration": "PT1H",
  "returnSuggestionReasons": "true",
  "minimumAttendeePercentage": "100"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a registered application, you have application permissions. Unfortunately, this method does not support this permission type.

Answer (score 0):

The POST /users/{id|userPrincipalName}/findMeetingTimes is not supported with application permissions as in the findMeetingTimes permissions docs. If you must use application permissions then try getSchedule to see if it will work for you.